# Изменение имени ключа в объекте

Tags: javascript

Есть объект.
var store = {
0: '0',
1: '1',
2: '2',
3: '3',
};
Есть функция, по вызову которой этот объект должен измениться и стать вот таким:
var store = {
0: '1',
1: '2',
2: '3',
};
То есть первая пара удаляется и все ключи становятся на единицу меньше.
И это нужно сделать в ES5 синтаксисе. В интернете я пока ничего не нашел.

---

Я сделал вот так:

```
delete store[0]; 
var bufStore = {}; 

for (var key in store) { 
    bufStore[key - 1] = store[key]; 
} 

store = bufStore;
```

Но мне нужно это реализовать без доп объекта. А по поводу массива, по заданию нельзя.

Comment: "В интернете я пока ничего не нашел" - а у самого какие мысли?

Comment: может вам объект заменить на массив?

Comment: Добавил свое решение. 

Но мне нужно это реализовать без доп объекта. А по поводу массива, по заданию нельзя.

Comment: А могут ли в исходном объекте быть «дырки»? Например `{0:0,1:1,3:3,4:4}`. Или «лишние» поля? `{0:0,a:2,1:1,2:2}`.

Answer (score 3):

Предполагается, что все ключи числовые:

```js
var store = { 0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3' };

shift(store);

console.log(store);

/***/
function shift(obj) {
  var key, prev_key;
  
  for (key in obj) {
    if (!prev_key) { // Первый ключ сохраняется в доп переменную.
      prev_key = key;
      continue;
    }
    
    obj[prev_key] = obj[key]; // каждое значение присваивается в предыдущее свойство  
    prev_key = key;
  }
  
  delete obj[key]; // последнее свойство удаляется
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагая, что на вход всегда приходят только «хорошие» объекты, можно написать цикл как для массива.

```js
var store = { 0: '0', 1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3' };

shift(store);

console.log(store);

function shift(obj) {
  for (var i = 0;; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) in obj) {
      // Есть есть свойство с номером (i+1), копируем его значение
      obj[i] = obj[i + 1];
    } else {
      // Последнее свойство удаляем и выходим из цикла
      delete obj[i];
      break;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const store = {
  0: '0',
  1: '1',
  2: '2',
  3: '3'
};

Object.keys(store).forEach((key, index, arr) => {
  const newKey = +key - 1;
  const value = store[key];
  store[newKey] = value;
// если значение < 0, то впринципе, можно и не сетить. Но так нагляднее. И все равно писать проверку
  if (newKey < 0) delete store[newKey];
  if (index === arr.length - 1) delete store[key];

});

console.log(store)
```